# jQuery Ajax call returning JSON string not as object array

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fetching data from database and showing the data in ASP.NET MVC view page as table format. Below is the Ajax call. I am getting the return data as JSON string. I am not sure why. For all view pages i am getting as JSON Object.

Though the value is getting in JSON string, i am trying to convert into JSON Object using "JSON.parse(jsonData)". It was working perfectly in my local. when i deploy the code in Stage. The Line is breaking at Json Parse.

Why i am getting this error. anything working in the code?

JSON String:

```
[{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c814:Supplier Needful Info.xlsx:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","DocDescription":"Paper Agreement","CreateDate":"05/11/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"40","AttachmentFilename":"Supplier Needful Info","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"PII Paper Agreement                               ","ContentType":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c2c2:WP_SQL_Query1.pdf:application/pdf","DocDescription":"Expense Report","CreateDate":"05/14/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"27","AttachmentFilename":"WP_SQL_Query1","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"Expense                                           ","ContentType":"application/pdf"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c2cc:UiPath-Level1_Certificate.pdf:applicat    ion/pdf","DocDescription":"Paper DOC","CreateDate":"05/14/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"40","AttachmentFilename":"UiPath-Level1_Certificate","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"PII Paper Agreement                               ","ContentType":"application/pdf"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c2e9:Communication Plan 865944.docx:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","DocDescription":"DOCS","CreateDate":"05/16/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"1","AttachmentFilename":"Communication Plan 865944","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"Insurance Documents                               ","ContentType":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c2ea:Communication Plan 865944.docx:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.docum    ent","DocDescription":"Amedments","CreateDate":"05/17/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"20","AttachmentFilename":"Communication Plan 865944","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"Amendment                                         ","ContentType":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c310:How to attach in OSA.pdf:application/pdf","DocDescription":"","CreateDate":"05/18/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"32","AttachmentFilename":"How to attach in OSA","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"EVP Attachment                                    ","ContentType":"application/pdf"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c2ec:WP_SQL_Query1.pdf:application/pdf","DocDescription":"","CreateDate":"05/18/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"27","AttachmentFi    lename":"WP_SQL_Query1","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"Expense                                           ","ContentType":"application/pdf"},{"SuppNum":null,"Documentumid":"090111738011c2ed:SyamOld_Passport.pdf:application/pdf","DocDescription":"","CreateDate":"05/18/2019","Userid":null,"LastChnageDate":null,"LastChnageUserid":null,"DocTypeCode":"27","AttachmentFilename":"SyamOld_Passport","ExpirtyDate":null,"IsDeleted":null,"DocTypeCodeDescription":"Expense                                           ","ContentType":"application/pdf"}]
```

AJAX CALL:

```
$("#btnVendorSearch").click(function() {
if (RequiredFieldValidate() != false) {
    var SupplierNumber = $('#txtVendorNumber').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getExactPath('/Supplier/GetSupDocuments'),
        async: false,
        data: {
            SupplierNo: SupplierNumber
        },
        dataType: 'Json',
        success: function(jsonData) {    
            var jsonobj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
            if (jsonobj.error == "" || jsonobj.error == undefined) {
                FillGrid(jsonobj);
            } else {
                console.log(jsonobj.error);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Unable to fetch the data");
        }});}});
```

Controller Method:

```
public JsonResult GetSupDocuments(string SupplierNo) {
    string Error = "";
    DocumentumUtil dUtil = new DocumentumUtil();
    List < Attachment > AttachmentDetails = new List < Attachment > ();
    try {
    AttachmentDetails = dUtil.GetSupplierAttachments(SupplierNo);
    return this.Json(AttachmentDetails);
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        Error = ex.Message;
    }
    return this.Json(new {error = Error});
}
```

It should Return as below. Please help me.

```
[object,object,object,object]
```

Comment: What is the error messages?

Comment: error : JSON is undefined

Comment: i just got it jQuery.parseJSON() is working. But i just want to know the difference between JSON.parse() /  jQuery.parseJSON() / JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON string is paring now into Array Object.

```
jQuery.parseJSON()
```